# Discord.js v12 TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made an add role command and added permissions to it. However, on running the command I get an error. Here is my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: "addrole",
    aliases: ["ar"],
    description: "Adds a role to a user",
    async execute(client, message, args) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return message.channel.send('NO PERMS')
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return message.channel.send('NO PERMS')
        const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
        if (!member)
            return message.channel.send('Please mention a user or provide a valid user ID');
        if (member.roles.highest.position >= message.member.roles.highest.position)
            return message.channel.send('You cannot add a role to someone with an equal or higher role');

        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[1]);

        let reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');
        if (!reason) reason = '`None`';
        if (reason.length > 1024) reason = reason.slice(0, 1021) + '...';

        if (!role)
            return message.channel.send('Please mention a role or provide a valid role ID');
        else if (member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) // If member already has role
            return message.channel.send('User already has the provided role');
        else {
            try {

                // Add role
                await member.roles.add(role);
                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('Add Role')
                    .setDescription(`${role} was successfully added to ${member}.`)
                    .addField('Moderator', message.member, true)
                    .addField('Member', member, true)
                    .addField('Role', role, true)
                    .addField('Reason', reason)
                    .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setColor(message.guild.me.displayHexColor);
                message.channel.send(embed);
            } catch (err) {
                return message.channel.send('Please check the role hierarchy or if the role is managed by an integeration or system', err.message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I had mentioned earlier I get an error:

```
(node:315) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/NonstopPastelDistributionsoftware/commands/addrole.js:7:20)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/NonstopPastelDistributionsoftware/index.js:80:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/NonstopPastelDistributionsoftware/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/NonstopPastelDistributionsoftware/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/NonstopPastelDistributionsoftware/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/NonstopPastelDistributionsoftware/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/NonstopPastelDistributionsoftware/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/NonstopPastelDistributionsoftware/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
(node:315) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:315) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I used the same code for permissions in every command however I got this error the first time. Can you help me out? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try making `const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');` into: `const Discord = require('discord.js')` (and obviously edit the embed)

Comment: add a console log above your first `if` statement and check what message actually entails